# What is the simplest way to merge a list of dictionaries with same value?

Tags: python

I would like to know is there a simple and efficient way to format this formal dictionary to the result as shown? Basically, the time key is used to group the dictionary and the value of variableName is used as key with value key as value.

For example here is the list of dictionary:

```
testdata =[{
  'frequency': 'monthly',
  'level': '1',
  'time': '2017 Jan',
  'value': 99.524,
  'variableCode': 'M212191.1',
  'variableName': 'All Items'},
 {'frequency': 'monthly',
  'level': '2',
  'time': '2017 Jan',
  'value': 105.12,
  'variableCode': 'M212191.1.0',
  'variableName': 'Food'},
 {'frequency': 'monthly',
  'level': '1',
  'time': '2017 Feb',
  'value': 99.521,
  'variableCode': 'M212191.1',
  'variableName': 'All Items'},
 {'frequency': 'monthly',
  'level': '2',
  'time': '2017 Feb',
  'value': 105.078,
  'variableCode': 'M212191.1.0',
  'variableName': 'Food'},
]
```

But I would like it to have the result in this following format:

```
testdata = [
   {
       'time': '2017 Jan',
       'All Items': 99.524,
       'Food':105.12
   },    
   {
       'time': '2017 Feb',
       'All Items': 99.521,
       'Food':105.078
   },
]
```

So far here is my progress which I am stuck with..

```
import itertools
import operator
import pprint

result = sorted(testdata, key = lambda i: i['time'])
list1 = []

for key, items in itertools.groupby(result, operator.itemgetter('time')):
   list1.append(list(items))

pprint.pprint(list1)
```

Output:

```
[[{'frequency': 'monthly',
   'level': '1',
   'time': '2017 Feb',
   'value': 99.521,
   'variableCode': 'M212191.1',
   'variableName': 'All Items'},
  {'frequency': 'monthly',
   'level': '2',
   'time': '2017 Feb',
   'value': 105.078,
   'variableCode': 'M212191.1.0',
   'variableName': 'Food'}],
 [{'frequency': 'monthly',
   'level': '1',
   'time': '2017 Jan',
   'value': 99.524,
   'variableCode': 'M212191.1',
   'variableName': 'All Items'},
  {'frequency': 'monthly',
   'level': '2',
   'time': '2017 Jan',
   'value': 105.12,
   'variableCode': 'M212191.1.0',
   'variableName': 'Food'}]]
```

Comment: First step is probably to use `itertools.groupby`.

Comment: Using `groupby` would be great, but it assumes the items are sorted by `time`. Is that true?

Comment: yes, it has to be sorted by time.

Comment: It's a little unclear when you say `it has to be sorted` does that mean it is **already** sorted or **needs** to be sorted?

Comment: I would like the result to be sorted by time yet at the same time with the resulting format as shown above. Hence to answer your question, it has not been sorted and needs to be sorted.

Comment: Sorting dates in the format `2017 Feb'` is going to be more work than the actual grouping. Do you have any flexibility with this format?

Comment: yes, I am flexible with the time format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close enough - just loop through the items once more.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

d = []

for k, grp in groupby(testdata,key=itemgetter("time")):
    temp = {"time":k}
    for i in grp:
        temp[i.get("variableName")] = i.get("value")
    d.append(temp)

print (d)
```

Result:

```
[{'time': '2017 Jan', 'All Items': 99.524, 'Food': 105.12}, {'time': '2017 Feb', 'All Items': 99.521, 'Food': 105.078}]
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Using `itertools.groupby`:**

```
import itertools

records = []

def get_dt(x):
    return x['time']

for key, group in itertools.groupby(testdata, get_dt):
    groups = list(group)
    rec = {}
    rec['time'] = key
    rec['All Items'] = sum([x['value'] for x in groups if x['variableName']=='All Items'])
    rec['Food'] = sum([x['value'] for x in groups if x['variableName']=='Food'])
    records.append(rec)

print(records)
# [{'time': '2017 Jan', 'All Items': 99.524, 'Food': 105.12},
#  {'time': '2017 Feb', 'All Items': 99.521, 'Food': 105.078}]
```

> Answer sourced from *[this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56412950/10521959)* from [How to create a list based on same value of a dictionary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56412904/how-to-create-a-list-based-on-same-value-of-a-dictionary-key)?